# Oracle how to "hide" table for other users

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle's 10g version.

In the database, I would like to create a configuration table and fill it with data.

Then the other users can not change anything in it, and even better that it was not at all visible to other users. Is it possible to somehow hide the table?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate schema for that table. Create a package that provides an API to your configuration data (e.g. to get a value that is needed by another program).

Revoke CREATE SESSION privilege from that schema (i.e. just don't grant any privileges to the schema at all). Don't grant any privileges on the table. The only users who will be able to see the table are those with DBA privileges.

The only thing that database sessions will be able to do is execute the package, IF they have been granted EXECUTE privilege on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not grant enough privileges to other users, they could not see your objects.